# Dispersion parameter in GAM output

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model

I have a question about Negative Binomial distribution. I’m modeling a count data, as following example:

```
require(MASS)
require(MGCV)
Model<-gam(A~B, family=nb)
```

Is the value returned at the top of a call to `summary()` the   overdispersion parameter?

Example:

```
summary(Model)

Family: Negative Binomial(0.502) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
A ~ s(B)
```

Is this value (0.502) the over dispersion parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, up to a caveat about what you mean by "overdispersion parameter".  In the standard parameterization of the negative binomial, this value is usually designated as $k$ or $\theta$, and controls the variance: $\textrm{Var} = \mu(1+\mu/k)$.  As $k \to \infty$ we get a Poisson: when $k=1$ we get a geometric distribution.

When in doubt, try experimenting: if I generate data from `rnbinom()` with a `size` parameter of 0.5, I get a value of $\approx 0.5$ back from `gam()`.

```
library(mgcv)
library(MASS)
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(y=rnbinom(1000,size=0.5,mu=5))
summary(gam(y~1,data=d,family=nb))

Family: Negative Binomial(0.529) 
[... snip ...]
```

Comment: if this answers your question, please consider clicking the checkmark to accept it ...